# SendwithDocusign button auto attaches documents

Tags: docusignapi

Send with Docusign does work however, I'm running into an issue where some accounts have attachments already added while others don't. We're not sure why documents are being auto attached and can't seem to get rid of them other than by manually closing them out.

I've tried creating a new button

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();
LA = '0';
```

but the issue still remains. If I try to edit the original button it get a message saying that it is managed and only certain attributes can be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of the attachments already added.  What examples are added and others that are not added?  Are you referring to the SF object that the completed docusign documents are attached to?